# Trying to escape ! in t-sql string

Tags: t-sql

how can I escape this?  I get a parse error because it's reading the ! literally or something

```
select [text] from someDB
where contains([text], '<![CDATA[')
```

Comment: If you change '<![CDATA[' to '"<![CDATA["', does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONTAINS is designed to search for words. You'd be better off using a LIKE (`LIKE '%<![[]CDATA[[]%'`) match for this.